# Best way to prevent repetition of Validation annotations in VIewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Viewmodel with about 30 input properties with decimal regex validation ie:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d+(\.\d{1,2})?", ErrorMessage = "Invalid decimal")]
public string strProperty { get; set; }
```

However I do not want to repeat this for every property. Is there a way to more central and DRY about this.

One idea is to define "\d+(.\d{1,2})?" as a constant.

Thanks....

Comment: following your idea of a `\d+(.\d{1,2})?` constant, you could implement a custom ValidationAttribute with this regex backed up in the validator.

Comment: If all your properties have the same validation applied, it seems like you have a very odd model. Could you make a collection of sub-types instead?

Comment: Declare the property as `float` or `decimal` and it will happen automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that comes to mind is inherit from `RegularExpressionAttribute`:

```
public class DecimalAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute {
    public DecimalAttribute() : base(@"\d+(\.\d{1,2})?") {
        this.ErrorMessage = "Invalid decimal";
    }
}
```

Then it becomes just:

```
[Decimal]
public string strProperty { get; set; }
```

That is assuming you know what you are doing and cannot just make property `decimal` instead of string.

Comment: Thanks for this. I agree just using the "decimal" type is the ideal way however I got into difficulty regarding specifying a custom error message, hence my SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42904883/best-way-to-control-error-message-for-decimal-validation-in-viewmodel-property-v

Comment: I didn't work with asp.net for a long time, but what if you both apply this attribute AND make field decimal?